# Курсы / уроки про svg анимацию?

Tags: svg

Есть задача сделать анимацию на svg и менять ее динамически на основе входящих данных.
Понимаю, что должен динамически рендерить элементы на svg.
Стоит вопрос как и на чем? 
По гуглив, почитал пару статей, пройдя курс на htmlacademy про svg, я до сих пор в тупике. 
Что использовать в качестве библиотеки для такой задачи?
Библиотек много d3,svg.js,snapsvg,gsap и т.д. 
Где достать достаточно современную информацию/учебник по svg?

Comment: https://svg-art.ru/

Comment: @DimenSi Обзорная статья -  как использовать SVG для создания  веб-анимации под все типы устройств  http://www.cmsmagazine.ru/library/items/graphical_design/how-to-use-svg/

Comment: спасибо, почитаю.